# Firebase Android Sending New Password after Reset

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have a pretty straightforward "Forgot Password" system setup. Seems to work just fine.

```
private void resetUser(final String email){
        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email) .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                    Toast.makeText(ForgotActivity.this, "Confirmation Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

The problem is that, once this password is changed, I also need to get the new password from Firebase because my login scheme uses both Firebase and the app server.  So, if they've changed the password on Firebase, and that password hasn't been sent to the app server's database... they won't be able to login.

So I need some sort of method to automatically send the new password back to the app once it is reset.

Is this possible?

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is impossible. There is no way to get the password from the user.

Comment: Could you just force the logout of the user after he pressed the resetPassword button ? I guess you push the new password at every new login ?

Btw, you should reconsider your architecture.. It's pretty weird to share Auth data as you intent to do.

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake I created most of the app before I started using Firebase, so I already had a login system. Plus I foresee a day when I won't need Firebase in the distant future, so it helps that all the data is already in my database. Also the user must already be logged out in order to press the resetPassword button. (It's on the login screen.)

Comment: @YayoArellano Where there's a will there's a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... This really couldn't have been easier:

First we take my original code and add send it back to a brand NewLoginActivity at the end:

```
private void resetUser(final String email){
    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email) .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                Toast.makeText(ForgotActivity.this, "Confirmation Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(ForgotActivity.this, "Enter New Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        ForgotActivity.this,
                        NewLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

In the NewLoginActivity FirebaseAuth verifies the new email and password combination and then sends them to update the password:

```
private void loginUser( final String email, final String password) {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updatePassword(email, password);
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {

                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(NewLoginActivity.this, "mAuth sign-in failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                    }
                });
}
```

This new login activity is exactly the same as the old one EXCEPT that when the user enters their email address and the new password... the new password is now saved to the database and this NewLoginActivity is only accessible from the ForgotPassword activity:

```
private void updatePassword(final String email, final String pass){
    Log.d(TAG, "Password Updated Line 359");

    String cancel_req_tag = "newpass";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_FOR_UPDATE, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Update Pass Response: " + response.toString());


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Update Pass Resp Error: Shit " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams () {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("pass", pass);
            return params;
        }
    };

    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
    Log.d(TAG, "Pass Request: " + strReq);

    Toast.makeText(NewLoginActivity.this, "Password Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Et VOILA! So the user resets their password... is sent to firebase to enter a new password... while they're doing that the app is sitting on an identical-looking but completely new login. They enter their email address and password, and now the new password is saved to both Firebase and the app database and the user is logged-in. Easy as pie!

I guess the only problem would be if the user closes the app before entering the new password... but you could create a SavedPreference or even modify the previous intent and just use it to send your original login to update the password. So... not only is it MORE than possible to get the new Firebase password... but there you've got about a million options for how to do it.